# How to store chosen radio button value in a AsyncStorage in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, radio-button, asyncstorage

I would like to store/save the users chosen radio button value in a AsyncStorage. How is this achieved? I am retrieving the radio button values from another file and assigning them to the labels. These are the structures of my radio buttons:

```
import RadioButtonRN from 'radio-buttons-react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const Radio = () => {
  const label1 = Questions[2].answers[0].answer;
  const label2 = Questions[2].answers[1].answer;
  const label3 = Questions[2].answers[2].answer;

  const data = [
    {
      label: label1,
    },
    {
      label: label2,
    },
    {
      label: label3,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <RadioButtonRN
      data={data}
      selectedBtn={(e) => console.log(e)}
      box={false}
      circleSize={14}
      activeColor={'#6175CF'}
      style={styles.radio}
    />
  );
};

export default Radio;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use javascript's `localStorage` to store and fetch values from session.
`setSelectedRadioBtn` sets the value in storage by name radioBtn and `getSelectedRadioBtn` gets the value stored in storage

```
setSelectedRadioBtn = (selectedBtn) => localStorage.setItem('radioBtn', selectedBtn);

getSelectedRadioBtn = () => console.log(localStorage.getItem('radioBtn'));

return (
        <RadioButtonRN
          data={data}
          selectedBtn={(e) => setSelectedRadioBtn(e)}
          box={false}
          circleSize={14}
          activeColor={'#6175CF'}
          style={styles.radio}
        />
  )
}
```